# Wait for a function to finish and then continue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro called `Setup` and inside it I have a function called `Game`. The macro start executing when a button is pressed, and then he calls `Game`, now, the macro continues to run without waiting for `Game` to finish, and then the calculations I do after `Game` are invalid because the game haven't finished yet.

- I want my macro to wait for `Game` to finish and then calculate the score based on the game.

```vb
Sub Setup()
    Game
    CalculateHighestScore
End Sub
```

**As you can see by the code above, `CalculateHighestScore` start without waiting for the game to finish and then the stats are just wrong**

Comment: I don't see that by the code above. `CalculateHighestScore` starts after `Game` completes.

Comment: @GSerg It actually doesn't. I can confirm that by saying that I also have another line in which I update other score on the board, and it starts when `Game` is being called, without waiting for `Game` to finish.

Comment: Is `Game` a sub in a VBA module not calling other outside application?

Comment: @FaneDuru `Game` is a function called from `Setup`, and not from anywhere else.

Comment: This is obvious from your code. My question was referring to the Sub/function itself. Doesn't it call an outside/external application? If not, your code should wait for the function to finish. This is the way VBA works. Now, it depends on the return of the function in discussion. Try inserting a `Stop` line between the two existing and press F5 after the code stops on it. Does it work in this way?

Comment: It is not possible in this code for `CalculateHighestScore` to run before `Game` completes. So either it doesn't, or you have wrong expectations about what *"`Game` completes"* means. It means that the macro has returned. It has. If inside that macro you started an asynchronous process, such as launched an external executable, then waiting for that process to finish is not a part of "`Game` completes", unless you specifically write code to make it such part. So we cannot help you without knowing what you are doing in `Game` so that simply returning from it does not work as "Completes" for you.

Comment: I totally agree with @GSerg comment above, but did you try adding `DoEvents` before `CalculateHighestScore` ?

Comment: @GSerg `It means that the macro has returned` After reading this I realized what the problem was. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure the variable/data required by *CalculateHighestScore* are GLOBAL, so that after *Game* function is executed the data is still valid and accessible to *CalculateHighestScore* function

if the function is extracting data from excel range, try adding

```
    Sub Setup()
        Game
        Application.calculate
        CalculateHighestScore
    End Sub
```

and check if it works, this will recalculate all excel formulas before processing CalculateHighestScore

Comment: `CalculateHighestScore` takes values from the sheet, i.e - `Range("L5").Value`.

Comment: check now, I have updated my answer, hope it works

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but likely it was because your answer makes assumptions about information that the OP has not provided.  If you do that, it's helpful to state up-front what assumptions you made.